# Accessing the filename in an HTTParty response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I am trying to parse the response from an api that has content type text/csv in a Ruby application. I am making the request using the HTTParty library. I know the filename is typically stored in the response headers under Content-Disposition, but HTTParty does not seem to be correctly parsing this particular header.

My best attempt at a fix looks like:

```
csv_response = HTTParty.get('service.com/csv')
content_disposition = CGI::parse(catalog_response.headers['Content-Disposition'])
```

This is where I'm stuck because CGI parse is returning a hash with the filename object containing a leading space and escaped quotes surrounding the filename like:

```
{' filename' => '\"file.csv\"'}
```

Am I parsing the response correctly? Is there a more reasonable way to access the filename using HTTParty?

Answer (score -2):

You don't want the filename. You can use CSV.parse instead.

```
csv_response = HTTParty.get('service.com/csv')
CSV.parse(csv_response.body, headers: true) do |row|
  # do something
end
```

Remove the `headers: true` if your CSV doesn't have a header row.